# Maxima: Recursively taking derivatives

Tags: recursion, maxima

I am trying to write some code that recursively finds Taylor coefficients by taking derivatives of a function and then once at the base case evaluates the derivatives at x=0. Here's the code I have so far:

```
test(f, n) := block([df],
        define(df(x), diff(f(x), x)),
        print(n, "|", df(x), "|", f(x)),
        if n = 0
        then f(0)
        else test(df, n-1)
        );

test_func(x) := x^2;

test(test_func, 2);
```

The trouble is that this is what I get:

```
(%i4) test(test_func,2)
           2
2 | 2 x | x  
1 | 2 | 2 
0 | 0 | 0 
(%o4)                                  0
```

As you can see, the first time through everything looks good, f(x) is x^2, df(x) is 2x. However, the second time through f(x) is 2, even though df(x) was 2x the last time through the function. I'm somewhat new to Maxima so it's quite possible that I'm simply missing something obvious (i.e. don't assume I'm not making a stupid mistake).

Comment: The specific reason it doesn't work as you expect is that by the time `print(..., f(x))` is evaluated the second time through, `f` has the value `df` which was just defined to be `df(x) := 2` so therefore `f(x)` evaluates to 2. The more general explanation is that definitions of named functions are symbol properties, not values, so when you make the recursive call `test(df, n - 1)` you are passing the name `df` and not the function definition of `df`. Maxima is approximately what is called a "Lisp-2", i.e., named functions are distinct from values. I agree that this is a confusing situation.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to work with expressions instead of named functions. Something like this:

```
test(e, n) := block([e1 : diff(e, x)],
  print(n, "|", e, "|", e1), 
  if n = 0
    then ev(e, x = 0)
    else test(e1, n - 1));
```

Comment: That works, but it doesn't exactly answer my question. Can you explain why what I did doesn't work?